# MVC 4 - Hide Controller In URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a area register routing:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "MyArea_default",
            "MyArea/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new string[] { "market.Areas.MyArea.Controllers" }
        );
    }
```

Its working as this, its ok:

**localhost:MyArea/ActionName**

But I hit F5 (in visual studio) when selected a specific view then url is:

**localhost:MyArea/Home/ActionName**

So how can work without controller name in url, when I hit f5 if a specific view selected?

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from your code:

localhost:MyArea/ActionName => Will use homeControllerClass with ActionName method.

localhost:MyArea/Home/ActionName => Will not work since it uses homeControllerClass but with ActionName "Home" !! That is it is looking for home method in homeControllerClass.

From you code:
"MyArea/{action}/{id}" 
 new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

=> It implies to use the homecontroller class for requests of MyArea with default action name of index if no action is specified.
So if you use MyArea/Home => it will use homeController but with action "Home".

{Controller}/{Action}

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use the costume route attribute.